# using Parallel.Foreach to read through all the files in a directory crashes my ide

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach

I wanted to create a simple snippet in .net core on vs code to look through a directory with hundreds of text files and give me all the filenames of the files that contain a certain string. This was my implementation

```
ConcurrentQueue<string> cb = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\\temp\\test"),
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Math.Floor((double)Environment.ProcessorCount/4) },
    (fp) => {
        using(var fs = File.OpenRead(fp))
        using(var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            while(!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains(args[0])){
                    cb.Enqueue(fp);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
catch(OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found!);
}
```

It runs for a few seconds and just crashes vs code. Is there anything that stands out?

Comment: bear in mind that in case of file reading/IO jobs the CPU isn't the bottleneck - so 2 threads won't give you twice performance

Comment: Did you try running your code without debugging? It is possible that you are dealing with a bug of VS Code, and not a bug of your code!

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for CPU-intensive computations on a lot of data, not file processing. That's why it uses all available cores and *doesn't* support asynchronous operations. You'll get a *lot* better performance if you use an ActionBlock<T> or TransformBlock class with a MaxDegreeOfParallelism  >1 and asynchronous operations like ReadLineAsync. Blocks already provide input/output queuing so there's no need for an additional ConcurrentQueue

Comment: I threw in a generic exception and put a break point in there like @HenkHolterman suggested but it never hits and weirdly enough it does just crash the ide today. So like fubo mentioned instead of Parallel.ForEach should I start each file in an async function and Task.WhenAll the list of the pending tasks?

Comment: On a completly different note: how do you manage to compile the code above? `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is an int and doesn't take a double and `Console.WriteLine("Found!);` is missing an `"`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the vs code process hangs after executing this block of code and a pop up comes up giving me the option to restart the process or kill it.

Comment: Don't catch `OperationCanceledException` only. Catch all exceptions like this: `catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex); }`, and tell us what you got.